# Netbeans warns blacklisted repository declarations for "http://download.java.net/maven/2" in pom.xml. How to deal?

Tags: java, maven, jsf, netbeans

In my maven based JSF project, I have these repositories added in my `pom.xml`

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>java.net2</id>
        <name>Repository hosting the jee6 artifacts</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        <id>jsf20</id>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <name>Repository for library Library[jsf20]</name>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

But Netbeans shows warnings that these reference blacklisted repositories. Should I remove these repository declarations ? Or do I need to replace them with some others ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The repository at http://download.java.net/maven/2 is deprecated, and has been replaced with https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/

This is why Netbeans details it as being blacklisted. This change to Netbeans was documented in the following bug: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=203736.

Simply change your URLs to point to the new repository and Netbeans should not complain any more.

Details on the java.net maven repository can be found here:
https://maven2-repository.java.net/